# Hide the status bar

Tags: android, frameworks

Please give me solution to hide the status bar of translucant screen, i have tries by setting Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen but it works for normal activity, but its not working for the screen witch is translucant.Please give me the hint to solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

That's how I usually do this by overriding one of standard themes.

```
<style name="ExampleTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

You then can apply the theme to your activity. I hope that helps.

Comment: But background screen is not tranperent, i want transperent screen

Comment: Then override transparent theme.

Comment: you can also set the @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen as theme for activity.

Comment: How to set two thems for same activity?

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style//Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen'

Comment: can someone tell me what 'android:windowNoTitle' does? for me 'android:windowFullscreen' works just fine

Answer (score 3):

Above solution is not work for me.
I used **"@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"** as parent theme.

```
<style name="ExampleTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status